# ParseException: Not well-formed (invalid token) while drawing route in Google map using KML

Tags: android, xml-parsing, google-places-api

I am new in google map place api. I want to draw a route between two points. I am using the code(part) for this in complete code. Here I am getting exception. Can anyone help me for this. Why i am getting this exception.

Thanks in advance.

```
String url = RoadProvider.getUrl(26.9114976,75.8065347, placeLatitide, placeLongitude);
InputStream is = getConnection(url);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(is);
inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
mRoad = RoadProvider.getRoute(inputSource);
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


public static Road getRoute(InputSource is) {
    KMLHandler handler = new KMLHandler();
    try {
            SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(is, handler);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //HERE I am getting exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return handler.mRoad;
}
```

Exception : `org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException`: At line 1, column 821: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: Personally, I'd look at line 1, column 821 of your input XML to see what the issue is.

Comment: @Eric thanks I found my solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=26.9114976,75.8065347&daddr=26.857126,75.812721&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml

I used this approach to draw route between two point in android.

This way of extracting the Google Directions from Google by parsing the KML file is no longer available since July 2012 (because Google has changed the structure of retrieving Google Directions, now we can only get it by JSON or XML), I migrate my code to JSON instead of KML.

It worked.!!

Thanks